# Precision in Euler number java

Tags: java

I'm doing a code that calculate  Euler number, but i haven't a good precision. If my i(variable to factorial) is 40, the code returns infinity, but, 20 or 30 the code return the number correctly

my code

```
double e = 1;
      for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
      {
           double j = (double)(E.factorial(i));
           double k = 1 / j;
           e = e + k;
      }
```

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` in place of `double`

Comment: As has been suggested, for precision of numbers that exceed the maximum value that can be held inside a regular data type, you should use BigDecimal. Having said that, I'm not sure if your E.factorial(i) function is under your control, so you may struggle to adapt to using BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `double` with `BigDecimal`. That would make the code precise.

```
BigDecimal e = 0;
BigDecimal demo = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 400; i++) {
        e += demo;
        demo /= i;
}
```

[Docs.oracle refer to this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDecimal instead of double.
[Documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/Essential-Classes/BigDecimal_class.htm)

Solution:

Here You can set the precision at the MathContext('precision' , ..)

```
 final static int LASTITER = 17;

          public static void main(String[] args) {
            MathContext mc = new MathContext(20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            for (int i = 0; i <= LASTITER; i++) {
              BigDecimal factorial = factorial(new BigDecimal(i));
              BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factorial, mc);
              result = result.add(res);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
          }

          public static BigDecimal factorial(BigDecimal n) {
            if (n.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO))
              return BigDecimal.ONE;
            else
              return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE)));
          }
```

Source: [math](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/Essential-Classes/Calculating_Eulers_number_e_with_BigDecimal.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think, that `E.factorial` returns `long` as result, to improve precision try this code:

```
    double e = 0;
    double tmp = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 400; ++i) {
        e += tmp;
        tmp /= i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as primitive type double can only have a maximum value of "1.7976931348623157e+308" (64bit precision) you'll need to use BigDecimal in order to achieve precision

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html